# Not getting Data back through a Task from Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port, task, cancellationtokensource

I have a question about tasks.
I want to open a new task and run a method.

```
public void runProgram(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(method1, token);
        //task 2 Just open a loading Dialog with a cancel button
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(method2, token);
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    }, token);
}
```

and the cancel button just cancel the task. That is working fine, but in method 1 I read data with `data = _MainForm.serialPort.ReadExisting();`
if I run the method without the task all is working fine, but if I run it with the task im not getting back any data. 
But I need the task if I want to cancel the execution...
What can I do there?

If I run it like that its also not working. Any Ideas? Should I give the task some objects from the Mainform or something like that?

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => 
{
    method1();
}, token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something within the context of a task changes a number of things that you may not be aware of, see when you use Task.Run your code is executing asynchronously in another thread, and if you try to interact with the UI from that thread it is possible to trigger a "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception which would result in the behaviour you have witnessed.

Say you had a TextBox called **textBox1** that you change once method1 completes, if you are just straight up assigning text like `textBox1.Text = "hello"` then you'd likely get an exception, instead you should try something like this:

```
public void updateTextBox(string newText)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action<string>)updateTextBox, newText);
        return;
    }
    textBox1.Text = newText;
}
```

In the above example I am assuming that you are using WinForms as you refer to forms in your question, however if you wanted to do something similar in WPF you could also do this:

```
public void updateTextBox(string newText)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<string>)updateTextBox, newText);
        return;
    }
    textBox1.Text = newText;
}
```

Whilst from my perspective it looks like your threads are aborting because an  exception is thrown when you try to access the UI somewhere, it may be something completely different. So on the off chance that I am wrong, please also consider sharing code for method1 and method2 so that we can make sure that your question is answered correctly.

Koda

Comment: Do you have any idea probably? I have still that problem if i use this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                method2();
            });

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot of code, i think thats too much.
I hope i  can describe it.
Method1 calling other methods in the sequence the user want to call them.

```
public void method1(){
    switch(sequence){
        case 1:
            method2();
            break;
        case 2:
            method3();
            break;
    }
```

like these and so on.... and in method2 im executing my code.

```
public void method2(int function){
    //Heres some code like:
    datas = helpfunction(function);
    portarray[1] = adress;    
    portarray[2] = datas;    
    _MainForm.serialPort.Write(portarray, 0, 4);
    data = _MainForm.serialPortPrüfling.ReadExisting();
    if(data != stringexample)
    {
        string ex = "Error";
        catch_exeption(null, ex);
        return;
    }
}
```

I added now this to my code at the beginning:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((Action<int>)method2, function);
    return;
}
```

Do this mean that the correct thread execute my function now???
Im new to this Theme im sorry :(